# Firefox only error with jQuery - handleObj.handler.apply is not a function

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm working on a plugin that expands Dan Grossman's rangepicker. [Here's my repo](https://github.com/yuvii/bootstrap-drpc). Please forgive my messy code, this is still a work in progress. My problem is that Firefox doesn't recognize clicking on the inputs. [This is](https://github.com/yuvii/bootstrap-drpc/blob/master/daterangepicker.js#L170) the relevant line:

```
this.container.find('.ranges')
    .on('click', 
        '.daterangepicker_start_input, .daterangepicker_end_input',   
        $.proxy(this.focusInput, this));
```

Now the function `focusInput` itself doens't matter, really, because I added a simple `console.log` at the top of it and it's very obvious it isn't being run at all (adding breakpoints didn't help either).

I thought it might be because I'm using disabled inputs, but changing that didn't help (and it shouldn't be a problem, as the event is caught through the parent element).

The error message I get from the Firefox console is:

```
TypeError: handleObj.handler.apply is not a function       jquery-1.11.0.js:4995
TypeError: handleObj.handler.apply is not a function       jquery-1.11.0.js:4624
```

Which tells me the issue is with jQuery (which I find hard to believe). I'm guessing I did something wrong that causes an error with jQuery, but as Chrome doesn't complain, I have a hard time tracing where exactly I went wrong.

I'd love to get some help on this. Thanks in advance!

**update**

I've updated the code in github. Now the clicking is not working only with elements that were hidden at first (which uh... doesn't make sense), but more importantly - *I'm not getting any errors at all*. So I'm stuck. I have no idea what's FF's problem. Even Internet Explorer isn't complaining - what the hell??

Comment: Doesn't this $.proxy(this.focusInput, this) need to be function(){ $.proxy(this.focusInput, this) } ?

Comment: @LShetty No. Other functions work just fine, and the whole thing is based on [Dan Grossman's rangepicker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker), which works fine in FF

Comment: Related: [“e.handler.apply” is not a function in jquery table sorter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283006/e-handler-apply-is-not-a-function-in-jquery-table-sorter)

Comment: I had the same problem and the common pitfall is: you have to pass in a **function reference** and **NOT a function invocation**!

Comment: i had a similar issue with firefox only, in my case it was coming from a tampermonkey script loaded (by mistake on the page i was coding locally, some too wild regex on the `@match`) that was reloading jQuery, undefining in the process all my functions that were extending $. probably not the same problem as yours at all  (looking at how you fixed it - although it is so weird you fixed it like this) but when i searched for my issue this question came top  so maybe my com will help somebody one day !

Answer (score 6):

Are any ranges available at the time when they are delegated to? The point of delegation is to target an element that you know will always exist and be visible, then delegate from there to elements that may come and go throughout the life of the script.

Try this:

```
this.container.on('click',
    '.ranges .daterangepicker_start_input, .ranges .daterangepicker_end_input',
    $.proxy(this.focusInput, this));
```

**UPDATE:**

I can reproduce this issue if I make a syntax error like so:

```
$('.target').on('click', '.thing', $.proxy(this.doStuff), this);
```

If I move the ) then it works as intended.

```
$('.target').on('click', '.thing', $.proxy(this.doStuff, this));
```

Do you have something similar happening? The code as you pasted it should be fine. [I made a jsFiddle to try and isolate the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/9k5tV/1/)

Comment: Actually, eventually I solved it by using `.on('click', 'input[type="text"]', ...)`. I'm still not sure what was the problem. Maybe you're right, and it was syntax. Still it's weird that only Firefox didn't work (which suggested my code was fine, because a syntax error should usually cause problems for all browsers). Anyway, thanks for the time you've taken +1

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I accidentally type the wrong function name `doStuff` below:

```
$.proxy(this.doStuff, this)
```

After I'd changed it to the correct name, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error for wrong syntax. Below is the code I typed while converting the function from `$(document).click(function(){ });` to `on('click')` function,

Wrong syntax I typed,

```
$(document).on('click',".removeDataTableItem").click(function(){
    // code block
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).on('click',".removeDataTableItem",function(){
    // code block
});
```