# "e.handler.apply" is not a function in jquery table sorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

In one of my application I am using JQUERY tablesorter.But while sorting with any of the cloumns I am getting below error. Any idea why this is happening.

Error : "e.handler.apply" is not function in Jquery.js

## My code to use table sorter is as below.

```
$(".tablesorter")
.tablesorter(
    {
        headers: { 0: { sorter: false}},
        widgets: ['zebra'],
        fixedHeight: false
    })
.tablesorterPager({
  container: $(".pager")
    });

$("#sortHeader").click(

    $(".tablesorter")
    .bind("sortStart",function(e, table) 
        {
            $('.tablesorter').trigger('pageSet',0);

        })

);
```

But If I am commenting the code which starts from "$("#sortHeader").click" then it is working fine. But I need that portion of code to meet my requirement.

Any thoughts on this.

Comment: For starters, do not bind events inside events (except when the original events have been destroyed). That connects them multiple times!

Comment: Also a sample with HTML (preferably in a JSFiddle) would be preferable on SO :)

Comment: Related: [Firefox only error with jQuery - handleObj.handler.apply is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588794/firefox-only-error-with-jquery-handleobj-handler-apply-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `function()` callback block of `click`:

```
$("#sortHeader").click(function(){ // <-----you need to have a callback function.
    $(".tablesorter").bind("sortStart",function(e, table){
        $('.tablesorter').trigger('pageSet',0);
    });
}); // <---do a proper closing.
```

---

### Issue in your code:

When you do :

```
$("#sortHeader").click(
```

without a callback function that will always gives you error in the jQuery library as you got to know *`Error : "e.handler.apply" is not function in Jquery.js`*

Because the way `.click()` method is written it needs a callback function to do something whenever you fire this event. so in your code jQuery thinks that whatever written in the `(...here...)` is a callback to the fired `click` event and it fails to apply that callback.

Comment: Thanks Jai.... It worked..... I am new in Jquery and not much aware of what is happening inside Jquery file.

Comment: @Jai way to go in terms of unsportsmanlike behaviour. I upvoted your answer which resulted in it getting accepted, but I answered first and you didn't vote at all, yet you expanded your answer with details that I included way ahead in mine.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester see i have not seen your answer when i was writing mine so that does not matter, yet if you feel that this is just i snatched an acceptance then its okay that is up to OP who can think which is the answer he/she can accept. Nonetheless for _unsportsmanlike behaviour_ +1 to you too. Yet if OP feels you answered it better he/she can change the acceptance i don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you must provide a function.

One way is to take the existing code in question, and wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$("#sortHeader").click( function() {
    $(".tablesorter")
    .bind("sortStart",function(e, table) 
        {
            $('.tablesorter').trigger('pageSet',0)
        })
    }
});
```

The other way is to give this function a name.  If you've given your function a name and are still having trouble, ensure that you have passed the function name *without* parentheses.

```
$("#sortHeader").click( myEventHanler );  // <-- function name without parens

myEventHanler() {
    $(".tablesorter")
    .bind("sortStart",function(e, table) 
        {
            $('.tablesorter').trigger('pageSet',0)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, what you're trying to do is to pass a parameter to jQuery's `click` function. More specifically, the return value of your call to `bind`, which just returns a jQuery object, which is **not** a function, hence `apply` is undefined on it and this results in the error that you're getting.

You need to wrap what you wrote inside `click()` in a function declaration:

```
$("#sortHeader").click( function(e) { //important!

$(".tablesorter")
.bind("sortStart",function(e, table) 
    {
        $('.tablesorter').trigger('pageSet',0);

    })

}); //close it too
```

Answer (score 0):

I incorrectly placed the third parameter of the [Underscore.js `debounce`](http://jashkenas.github.io/underscore/#debounce) function, which somehow caused the same error.

Bad:

```
$('#color_search_text').keyup(_.debounce(processSearch,
        MILLS_TO_IGNORE_SEARCH), true);
```

Good:

```
$('#color_search_text').keyup(_.debounce(processSearch,
        MILLS_TO_IGNORE_SEARCH, true));
```