# What should `data` variable from "inner" success AJAX, be changed to when moved to an "outer" version?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an html table of yes/no (textual) like buttons, and the below JavaScript that passes the click-requests onto the server. I'm transforming this javascript, which manually prevents rapid-fire clicks:

```
var MILLS_TO_IGNORE_LIKES = 500;
var processLike = function()  {

    //In this scope, "this" is the button just clicked on.
    //The "this" in processLikeInner is *not* the button just clicked on.
    var $button_just_clicked_on = $(this);

    //The value of the "data-color_id" attribute.
    var color_id = $button_just_clicked_on.data('color_id');

    var processLikeInner = function(data, textStatus_ignored, jqXHR_ignored)  {
        //alert("sf data='" + data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");
        $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + color_id).html(data);

        //Don't process requests too close together:

        console.log('Like disabled for: ' + MILLS_TO_IGNORE_LIKES);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $button_just_clicked_on.one('click', processLike);
            console.log('Like re-enabled for color_id ' + color_id + ' ');
        }, MILLS_TO_IGNORE_LIKES);
    }

    var config = {
        url: LIKE_URL_PRE_ID + color_id + '/',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: processLikeInner
    };
    $.ajax(config);
};

$(document).ready(function()  {
    /*
        There are many buttons having the class

            td__toggle_color_like_button

        This attaches a listener to *every one*. Calling this again
        would attach a *second* listener to every button, meaning each
        click would be processed twice.

        When a button is clicked, the listener for that *single button*
        is disabled. It's re-enabled in processLikeInner with

            $button_just_clicked_on.one('click', processLike);
     */
    $('.td__toggle_color_like_button').one('click', processLike);
});
```

to this version that uses [Underscore](http://jashkenas.github.io/underscore/). What should "data" (the variable in `html(data)`) be changed to?

```
var MILLS_BTWN_LIKES = 500;
$(document).ready(function()  {
    /*
        There are many buttons having the class

            td__toggle_color_like_button

        This attaches a listener to *every one*. Calling this again
        would attach a *second* listener to every button, meaning each
        click would be processed twice.

        When a button is clicked, the listener for that *single button*
        is disabled. It's re-enabled in processLikeInner with

            $button_just_clicked_on.one('click', processLike);
     */
    $('.td__toggle_color_like_button').click(_.debounce(function(e){
        colorId = $('.td__toggle_color_like_button').data('color_id');
        //console.log("colorId='" + colorId + "'");
        $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + colorId).html(data);  //<-- here
    }, MILLS_BTWN_LIKES));
});
```

Comment: You need to run your ajax function there else you won't be running it, `data` is the server response

Comment: Thanks. My mistake is once again mixing both AJAX and JQuery together, and thinking Underscore is a replacement for everything (I've completely eliminated the server call, as you noticed). The benefit of Underscore is for eliminating the "rapid fire click prevention" section only. Working on it now.

Comment: Yes, it mostly eliminates only the `processLikeInner` function and the main function (just the wrap), the rest need to be moved inside the click event, or you can leave them outside and call  `$.ajax(config).done(function(data){ /* use data here */})`

Comment: @Spokey: Consider elaborating in an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the ajax request was left out when you changed to Underscore.js. To be able to use `data` you must complete the ajax request first, meaning you must move the ajax logic inside the click handler.

```
var MILLS_BTWN_LIKES = 500;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.td__toggle_color_like_button').click(_.debounce(function (e) {
        console.log('Like disabled for: ' + MILLS_BTWN_LIKES);

        var colorId = $(this).data('color_id'),
            config = {
                url: LIKE_URL_PRE_ID + color_id + '/',
                dataType: 'html'
            };

        $.ajax(config).done(function (data) {
            $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + colorId).html(data);
        });

    }, MILLS_BTWN_LIKES));

});
```

This however brings up an issue if the request actually finishes successfully and under 500ms. You should also consider using a `fail` handler for unsuccessful requests.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is, if it successfully completes in under 500ms?

Comment: Was referring if the request does not finish in 500ms. Not sure how your server-side handles the request. It may not be an issue. It simply means that the user can click again and make a new request before the other one was completed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, duplicated from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28332782/2736496). This only requires `underscore-min.js`, not `underscore-min.map`.

```
/**
    The number of milliseconds to ignore clicks on the *same* like
    button, after a button *that was not ignored* was clicked. Used by
    `$(document).ready()`.

    Equal to <code>500</code>.

    The disabling and re-enabling is logged to the console.
 */
var MILLS_TO_IGNORE_LIKES = 500;
```

Continued: Processor function

```
/**
   Executes a like click. Triggered by clicks on the various yes/no
   links.

   The disabling and re-enabling is logged to the console.

   See <link to MILLS_TO_IGNORE_LIKES>
 */
var processLike = function()  {

   //In this scope, "this" is the button just clicked on.
   //The "this" in processServerResponse is *not* the button just clicked
   //on.
   var $button_just_clicked_on = $(this);

   //The value of the "data-color_id" attribute.
   var color_id = $button_just_clicked_on.data('color_id');

   var processServerResponse = function(sersverResponse_data, textStatus_ignored,
                                        jqXHR_ignored)  {
       //alert("sf sersverResponse_data='" + sersverResponse_data + "', textStatus_ignored='" + textStatus_ignored + "', jqXHR_ignored='" + jqXHR_ignored + "', color_id='" + color_id + "'");
       $('#toggle_color_like_cell_' + color_id).html(sersverResponse_data);
   }

   var config = {
       url: LIKE_URL_PRE_ID + color_id + '/',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: processServerResponse
       //Should probably include a "fail" call, too.
   };
   $.ajax(config);
};
```

Continued: Main function:

```
/**
   The Ajax "main" function. Attaches the listeners to the elements on
   page load.
 */
$(document).ready(function()  {
    /*
        There are many buttons having the class

            td__toggle_color_like_button

        This attaches a listener to *every one*. Calling this again
        would attach a *second* listener to every button, meaning each
        click would be processed twice.

        ---

        Warning: Placing the true parameter outside of the debounce call:

        $('#color_search_text').keyup(_.debounce(processSearch,
            MILLS_TO_IGNORE_SEARCH), true);

        results in "TypeError: e.handler.apply is not a function"
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283006/e-handler-apply-is-not-a-function-in-jquery-table-sorter
        - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588794/firefox-only-error-with-jquery-handleobj-handler-apply-is-not-a-function
    */
    // API: http://jashkenas.github.io/underscore/#debounce
    $('.td__toggle_color_like_button').click(_.debounce(processLike,
            MILLS_TO_IGNORE_LIKES, true));
});
```